# Awk iterating with out a loop construct

Tags: awk

I was reading a tutorial on `awk` scripting, and observed this strange behaviour, Why this awk script while executing asks for a number repeatedly even with out a loop construct like `while` or `for`. If we enter `CTRL+D`(EOF) it stops prompting for another number.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    print "type a number";
}
{
    print "The square of ", $1, " is ", $1*$1;
    print "type another number";
}
END {
    print "Done"
}
```

Please explain this behaviour of the above awk script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` continues to work on lines until end of file is reached. Since in this case the input (**STDIN**) never ends as you keep entering number or hitting enter, it causes an endless loop.

When you hit **CTRL+D** you indicate the `awk` script that **EOF** is reached there by exiting the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this and enter 0 to exit

```
BEGIN {
    print "type a number";
}
{
    if($1==0)
       exit;
    print "The square of ", $1, " is ", $1*$1;
    print "type another number";
}
END {
    print "Done"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the famous [The AWK Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020107981X):

If you don't provide a input file to the awk script on the command line, awk will apply the program to whatever you type next on your terminal until you type an end-of-file signal (control-d on Unix systems).